# Use of the MAX function - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query in BiqQuery, where I need to return only the max value for visitNumber.

```
SELECT
fullvisitorid,
max(VisitNumber),
NTILE(10) OVER (order by visitnumber DESC) ntile,
FROM
[data]
GROUP BY fullvisitorid,visitnumber
```

Currently, I get this:

```
Row   fullvisitorid     f0_   ntile  
1   5525864130868838188 8371    1    
2   5525864130868838188 8370    1    
3   5525864130868838188 8369    1    
4   5525864130868838188 8368    1    
5   5525864130868838188 8367    1    
6   5525864130868838188 8366    1    
7   5525864130868838188 8365    1
```

Whereas, want I want is this i.e. only the max visitnumber, for the fullvisitorid.

```
 Row      fullvisitorid     f0_   ntile  
  1    5525864130868838188  8371    1
  2    1450600973472850688  7461    1
  3    6249134003569839962  6914    1
  4    3072340487595905048  6828    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a rank to the visit number of each `fullvisitorid` partition.  Then, retain only the first record from each partition.  Note that in the case of ties, `DENSE_RANK()` would match multiple records in this case.

```
SELECT
    t.fullvisitorid,
    t.VisitNumber,
    t.ntile
FROM
(
    SELECT
        fullvisitorid,
        VisitNumber,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorid ORDER BY VisitNumber DESC) dr,
        NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY visitnumber DESC) ntile
    FROM [data]
) t
WHERE t.dr = 1
```